# Tabular problem with long tables

Tags: tables, longtable

I wrote the following code to produce a long table. However the result is not as desired

```
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]

\newcommand{\Summary}{BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA \\ 
BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA  \\
BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA \\
BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA \\
BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA \\
BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA}

\newcommand{\TabularEnvironment}[1]{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}p{\linewidth}@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}

\definecolor{lightgray}{HTML}{EFEFEF}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{.5pt}

\begin{longtable}{|>{\columncolor{lightgray}} p{0.2\linewidth} | p{0.175\linewidth} | p{0.175\linewidth} |}
\noalign{\nobreak\vskip-.5pt} \hline\noalign{\nobreak\vskip.5pt}  
Here & Here & Here
\\[.5pt]\noalign{\nobreak\vskip-.5pt} \hline\noalign{\nobreak\vskip.5pt} 
\endfirsthead
\noalign{\nobreak\vskip-.5pt} \hline\noalign{\nobreak\vskip.5pt}  
Here & Here & Here
\\[.5pt]\noalign{\nobreak\vskip-.5pt} \hline\noalign{\nobreak\vskip.5pt} 
\endhead
\noalign{\nobreak\vskip-.5pt} \hline\noalign{\nobreak\vskip.5pt} 
\endfoot
foo & bar & dada \\[.5pt]\noalign{\nobreak\vskip-.5pt} \hline\noalign{\nobreak\vskip.5pt}
foo & bar & dada \\ \cline{2-2}
foo & bar & dada \\ \cline{2-2}
foo & bar & dada \\ \cline{2-2}
foo & bar & dada \\ \cline{2-2}
foo & bar & \TabularEnvironment{\Summary} \\ \cline{2-2}
foo & bar & dada \\ \cline{2-2}
foo & bar & dada \\ \cline{2-2}
foo & bar & dada \\ \cline{2-2}
foo & bar & dada \\ \cline{2-2}
foo & bar & dada \\[.5pt]\noalign{\nobreak\vskip-.5pt} \hline\noalign{\nobreak\vskip.5pt}
\caption{Your caption here} % needs to go inside longtable environment
\label{tab:myfirstlongtable}
\end{longtable} 

\end{document}
```

Here is the problem:

[image]

The page is cut and not all the words are displayed, I know the problem with the variable \tabularenvironment but I don't know how to solve it. Any help?

Comment: `longtable` cannot be broken in the middle of the row. Please add preamble to your code fragment!

Comment: I don't understand your answer, I used \endfoot - \endfirsthead and \endhead

Comment: `longtable can be broken only between rows! Your cell "\Summary" is to tall and cannot be fir on one page. This featurews have nothing with `\endfoot` - `\endfirsthead` and `\endhead`.  You need to redesign your table. Please read package documentation for details.

Comment: Is there a walk around by adding a new page in \summary ?

Comment: No. Please read documentation of `longtable`. All what you can do, is manually split row with this cell into two (or more) rows. But doing this, you will be faced with new problems ... /what to do with contents in adjacent cells :-( /